# Robotframework: Javascript replace string not working

Tags: javascript, selenium, robotframework

I'm writing some Robotframework tests and I need to redirect to a different url in case AB test is up.

I tried by using builtin and selenium but I find myself more comfortable by using JS, and here goes what I wrote to do this:

```
var url = location.href.toString();

function check(){
if (url.includes("preventivo-c")){
    return true;
 }
};
check();
if (check() === true){
    let newUrl = url.replace("preventivo-c", "preventivo");
    window.location.href = newUrl;
};
```

Inside Robot it's something like this:

```
${prevNew}=    execute javascript             const url = location.href.toString();       function check(){if (url.includes("preventivo-c")){return true;}};   check();    if (check() === true){let newUrl = url.replace("preventivo-c", "preventivo");window.location.href = newUrl;};
```

When I execute the tests it says

```
InvalidArgumentException: Message: invalid argument: 'url' must be a string
```

I tried debugging my code on Chrome console and it works fine. Console.log(typeof url) returns "string" so I don't see why I'm getting this error.

Comment: Note related to the error, but replace does not alter the original string.

Comment: @epascarello you're right, I modified the code quickly and now it does the trick. Still the core problem persists.

Comment: my guess the issue is maybe the variable name, hard to tell

Comment: I don't get the error you say you get when I run that command in firefox and chrome. For me, the replace works just fine.